# What am I doing wrong here? While loop and character issues

Tags: c, while-loop

So I'm quite new to using while loops and am stuck here. Would anyone be able to help me on this one or point me in the right direction? It's a part of a larger program I am trying to create. Thanks for any help!

It's supposed to continue asking until "q" is entered.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int height, feet, inches;
    char name[30];
    while (name!='q')
    {
        printf("Enter height and first name: ");
        scanf("%d %s", &height, &name);
        inches = height%12;
        feet = height / 12;
        printf("%s's height is %d feet and %d inches.\n", name, feet, inches);
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

I noticed when I enter to end the loop, the program goes mad and starts printing the first line of the loop infinitely.

Comment: You don't need a loop at all...

Comment: You asked for height then name, and expect height then name, yet you typed in name height. Also, as Dai said you don't need a while loop.

Comment: There's no loop needed here. It's two lines of code to convert inches into feet and inches, with absolutely no need to loop.

Comment: Okay I misread what I needed to do and redid the program. Now a new problem has risen, I can't get anything to happen when I run the program

Comment: Note that the compiler should be warning you about the comparison in `while (name != 'q');` as you're comparing a pointer and an `int`, and the semicolon is misplaced (delete it!).  You probably want to use `strcmp()`, but you need to initialize `name` before the first iteration.  You do need the `while` loop if you're going to do many conversions, but the printing of the result should be inside the loop too.  Or if you want one shot, the loop is unnecessary, and so's the test.  You should test that `scanf()` returns 2; if it doesn't, you didn't get all the information you requested.

Comment: @Dai How is that?

Comment: @SurajJain The OP has changed their question - their original posting used a loop to perform division, it didn't have an input loop. My comment no-longer applies.

Comment: @Dai Oh, ok. I was Wondering.

Comment: Sorry about changing it. Next time I'll add to my original post instead of changing it completely. Thanks for your help here either way! I got it running :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `while (name!='q')` with `while(name[0]!='q')`

It'll work just fine.

Comment: For some reason, I'm a bit confused on what using brackets with a number inside when defining character variables actually does. When I change the number around, it doesn't seem to make a difference to me. For example, I thought when I used "char c[5]" to define c, and then use scanf to enter in a string for c, that 5 would limit what I enter to just 5 characters. But that doesn't seem to be the case. Or maybe I'm horribly mistaken. Either way, I digress. I figured out the program and got it working. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Well, you are welcome. If my suggestion helped, be kind enough to upvote it.

Answer (score 2):

```
while (name!='q');
```

You can't compare strings like this in C. You need to use `strcmp`, for example `while (strcmp(name, "q"))`.

Which book are you reading? This is often emphasised in decent books, early on.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! To you and to everyone! I got it running properly last night not long after your helpful tips.

Comment: You can't rely upon the tips of people online, as not all of us are reputable in the field of teaching and programming.

Comment: Whether anyone is or isn't, some help is better than none. I want to become knowledgeable in programming in C and other languages so that eventually I'll be reputable enough to answer other's questions, instead of always asking them.